# redirect on the same post_id after edit post

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have created a forum website in Django where users can post Questions/Answers and edit them.
After editing the reply I want to redirect the user to the currently edited post page. like if user
edit reply which has been posted on the question with id 4 (which url is (http://127.0.0.1:8000/discussion/4)) then after edited it should redirect to the same URL. After editing, and deleting the reply I am redirecting the user to the forum homepage but I want to redirect to the `/discussion/{post_id}` URL(which is URL of the particular post on which reply being edited and deleted)

urls.py

```py
app_name = "dashboard"
urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('user_home', views.user_home, name="user_home"),
    path('admin_home', views.admin_home, name="admin_home"),
    path("forum", views.forum, name="forum"),
    path("discussion/<int:myid>", views.discussion, name="discussion"),
    path("showallusers", views.show_all_users, name="showallusers"),
    path('delete_user/<int:pk>', views.delete_user, name="delete_user"),
    path('delete_post/<int:pk>', views.delete_post, name="delete_post"),
    path('delete_reply/<int:pk>', views.delete_reply, name="delete_reply"),
    path('upload_notes', views.upload_notes, name='upload_notes'),
    path('view_mynotes', views.view_mynotes, name='view_mynotes'),
    path('delete_mynotes/<int:pk>/', views.delete_mynotes, `name='delete_mynotes'), `
    path('pending_notes', views.pending_notes, name='pending_notes'),
    path('assign_status/<int:pk>', views.assign_status, name='assign_status'),
    path('accepted_notes', views.accepted_notes, name='accepted_notes'),
    path('rejected_notes', views.rejected_notes, name='rejected_notes'),
    path('all_notes', views.all_notes, name='all_notes'),
    path('delete_notes/<int:pk>', views.delete_notes, name='delete_notes'),
    path('delete-records/', views.delete_notes, name='delete_notes'),
    path('view_allnotes', views.view_allnotes, name='view_allnotes'),
    path('notessharing', views.notessharing, name='notessharing'),
    path('edit_post/<int:pk>/', views.edit_post, name='edit_post'),
    path('edit_reply/<int:pk>/', views.edit_reply, name='edit_reply'),
]
```

delete_reply code

```py
def delete_reply(request, pk=None):
    reply = Replie.objects.filter(id=pk)
    reply.delete()
    return redirect('/forum')
```

After deleting a reply from a post I want to redirect to the same post.

models.py

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    user1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    post_id = models.AutoField
    post_content = models.TextField(max_length=5000,verbose_name="")
    timestamp= models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images",default="")
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user1} Post'

class Replie(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    reply_id = models.AutoField
    reply_content = models.TextField(max_length=5000,verbose_name="")
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    timestamp= models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images",default="")
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user1} Post'
```

views.py

```py
def forum(request):
    user = request.user
    profile = Profile.objects.all()
    if request.method=="POST": 
        form=PostContent(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():  
            user = request.user
            image = request.user.profile.image
            content = request.POST.get('post_content','')
            post = Post(user1=user, post_content=content, image=image)
            post.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your Question has been posted successfully!!')
            return redirect('/forum')
        else:
            form=PostContent()  
    posts = Post.objects.filter().order_by('-timestamp')
    form= PostContent()
    context={
        'posts':posts,
        'form':form
    }
    return render(request, "forum.html",context)


def discussion(request, myid):
    post = Post.objects.filter(id=myid).first()
    replies = Replie.objects.filter(post=post)
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=ReplyContent(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():  
            user = request.user
            image = request.user.profile.image
            desc = request.POST.get('reply_content','')
            post_id =request.POST.get('post_id','')
            reply = Replie(user = user, reply_content = desc, post=post, image=image)
            reply.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your Reply has been posted successfully!!')
            return redirect(f'/discussion/{post_id}')
        else:
            form=ReplyContent()
    form= ReplyContent()
                
    return render(request, "discussion.html", {'post':post, 'replies':replies,'form':form})    


def edit_reply(request, pk):

    reply = Replie.objects.get(id=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateReplyForm(request.POST, instance=reply)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,"Reply updated successfully!")
            return redirect('/forum')
    else:
        form = UpdateReplyForm(instance=reply)
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'edit_reply.html', context)
```

edit_post view

```py
def edit_post(request, pk):

    post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdatePostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Post updated successfully!")
            return redirect('/forum')
    else:
        form = UpdatePostForm(instance=post)
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'edit_post.html', context)
```

Currently, after editing the reply, I am redirecting the user to the post home page but I want to redirect to `/discussion/{post_id}`.

Template code:
edit_reply.html

```html
{% load static %}
{% block body %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<div class="container ">
    <form method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4 mt-4 f2" >Update Reply</legend>
            </fieldset>
            <label style="font-size:1rem; font-weight:bold;">Reply Content</label>
            {{form|crispy}}
            <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{post_id}}"> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <button href="" class="btn btn-primary" type="Update">
                     Update
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

Comment: please provide templates of this project

Comment: Don't ever do this `return redirect(f'/discussion/{post_id}')`. Use `reverse` and URL names. You'll thank me later.

Comment: To answer the question we need to know (at least) the relationship fields (ForeignKey etc.)  in your models `Post`, `Replie` and any other relevant ones. Also clarify what is meant by "redirect to same URL".

Comment: redirect to the same URL means the URL of that Post on which reply is being edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect it to `discussion` view with its `pk` by passing `args=[reply.post.id]` in `edit_reply` view.

Try this:
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse

def edit_reply(request, pk):
    reply = Replie.objects.get(id=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateReplyForm(request.POST, instance=reply)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Reply updated successfully!")
            return redirect(reverse('dashboard:discussion', args=[reply.post.id]))
    else:
        form = UpdateReplyForm(instance=reply)
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'home/edit_reply.html', context)
```

> `Note:` Forms in django required `Form` to be the suffix, so it will be better if it changed to `PostContentForm` and `ReplyContentForm` from `PostContent` and `ReplyContent` respectively.

It must be

```
return f'{self.user} Post'
```

not

```
return f'{self.user`} Post'
```

As it is not any field in `Replie` model.

> `Note:` ForeignKey's names are generally written in its own name and that too in `snake_case`, it will be better if you change `user1` to `user` in `Post` model.

For better understanding:

If table name is `PizzaTopingCategory` so while creating ForeignKey you should name it as

```
pizza_toping_category=models.ForeignKey(PizzaTopingCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

### Edit:

You need to find out `post_id`, so you can send it through:

Try this in the `delte_reply` view:

```py
def delete_reply(request, pk=None):
    reply = Replie.objects.filter(id=pk)
    reply_instance = get_object_or_404(Replie,id=pk)
    post_pk=reply_instance.post.id
    
    reply.delete()
    return redirect(reverse('dashboard:discussion', args=[post_pk]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Sunderam Dubey It works But I have other redirection problems in my project like this problem. in delete post reply, and posting a question on the forum. I have provided my delet_reply view code

Comment: @Ajay What error did you get?

Comment: @Ajay After deleting reply do you want again it goes to discussion page with respective id? So, do the same.

Comment: @Ajay only pass `args=[pk]` and see if it works.

Comment: @Ajay Yes, it will happen since its replie id, not post id, which `discussion` view want.

Comment: @Ajay From the next time, please ask single questions and see how do I make a minimal reproductible example [repro].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245122/discussion-between-ajay-and-sunderam-dubey).

Answer (score 1):

For passing `pk` in `discussion` view, you should write `return redirect(reverse('dashboard:discussion', args=[reply.post.id]))` in `edit_post` view:

views.py

```
def edit_post(request, pk):

    post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdatePostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Post updated successfully!")
            return redirect(reverse('dashboard:discussion', args=[post.id]))
    else:
        form = UpdatePostForm(instance=post)
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'home/edit_post.html', context)
```